# Turtle Graphics path using a string

Tags: python

**Edit: I managed to fix it.**

...

I don't know too much about Python but I'm trying to write a function that uses Python's Turtle Graphics to draw a simple path based on the characters in the string.

So, for example, if string = "FRRL" then the turtle should move forward, right, right, left.

When I run this code:

```
import turtle

step = 100
angle = 90

t = turtle.Turtle()

t.forward(step)
t.left(angle)
t.right(angle)

turtle.done()
```

It gives a different output to the one I am trying to make below:

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()   
S = "FLR"
step = 100
angle = 90

for i in S:

    if i == 'F' or 'E':
        t.forward(step)

    if i == 'L':
        t.left(angle)

    if i == 'R':
        t.right(angle)

turtle.done()
```

The code runs but it seems that in this one it moves the turtle the direction it's facing (so forward I guess) on top of what the if i == '...': t....(angle/step) is telling it to do. So, for example if i == 'R', it will move it forward first and then turn it by 90 degrees to the right, instead of just turning it - same for i == 'F' and i == 'L'. It moves all of them forward first before carrying out the turtle move I want it to.

How do I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: For me your second code works just fine

Comment: @TobiasWilfert The code runs but it doesn't draw the same thing as the first one, so I assume it's not correct? For me it always moves it forward first before doing a turtle move I want it to.

Comment: Well, it checks ever 'char' in S and the first char is F so it moves forward then turns left and right.

Comment: please consider adding 2 pictures because for me both codes give exactly the same outcome.

Comment: @TobiasWilfert This is what I get when I use the string = "FLR": https://prnt.sc/lmbbho  and this is what I get when I do it the other way: https://prnt.sc/lmbbj0 - When i use the string it always moves it forward first for me and then does the "F" "L" or "L" after moving it forward first, I don't know why and I don't want it to move forward each time. Any ideas why I don't get the same output?

Comment: @TobiasWilfert nevermind, I fixed it. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by changing

```
if i == 'F' or 'E':
```

to

```
if i in ['F', 'E']:
```

and now it works as it should.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments, I guess (and this is bad, as you should have given more details about that) you expect that when the letter is "L" the turtle would turn left based on "angle" AND walk the "step".

So, in this case, you missed the forward walk, and this would be the right addition to do so:

```
if i == 'L':
    t.left(angle)
    t.forward(step)

if i == 'R':
    t.right(angle)
    t.forward(step)
```

PS: In any case, both versions you posted work the same for me!

Comment: No, that's what I don't want. It moves the turtle forward regardless of what the letter is 'F', 'L' and 'R' and THEN does the 'F' 'L' or 'R'  operation after moving it forward. I don't want it to move forward every time. Do you have any idea why it does not work the same for me?

Comment: When I use my string = "FLR", I get this: https://prnt.sc/lmbbho and when I do it the other way I get this output and they're not the same for me: https://prnt.sc/lmbbj0 - using the string it moves the turtle forward each time before doing the "F", "L" or "R" move and I don't want it to go forward each time. Not sure why it does that. Any ideas?

Comment: You're welcome! Glad that I helped somehow. Now I understood that the problem was in the condition if i == "F" or "E", because it'll always be true, and "E" is always true as a condition.